# Simple Instaparse parser with sub-expression syntax

Tags: parsing, clojure

I'm using Instaparse to parse expressions like:

`$(foo bar baz $(frob))`

into something like:

`[:expr "foo" "bar" "baz" [:expr "frob"]]`

I've almost got it, but having trouble with ambiguity. Here's a simplified version of my grammar that repros, attempting to rely on negative lookahead.

```
(def simple
  (insta/parser
    "expr = <dollar> <lparen> word (<space> word)* <rparen>
     <word> = !(dollar lparen) #'.+' !(rparen)
     <space> = #'\\s+'
     <dollar> = <'$'>
     <lparen> = <'('>
     <rparen> = <')'>"))

(simple "$(foo bar)")
```

which errors:

```
Parse error at line 1, column 11:
$(foo bar)
          ^
Expected one of:
")"
#"\s+"
```

Here I've said a word can be any char, in order to support expressions like:

`` $(foo () `bar` b-a-z) ``

etc. Note a word can contain `()` but it cannot contain `$()`. Not sure how to express this in the grammar. Seems the problem is `<word>` is too greedy, consuming the last `)` instead of letting `expr` have it.

---

**Update** removed whitespace from word:

```
(def simple2
  (insta/parser
    "expr = <dollar> <lparen> word (<space> word)* <rparen>
     <word> = !(dollar lparen) #'[^ ]+' !(rparen)
     <space> = #'\\s+'
     <dollar> = <'$'>
     <lparen> = <'('>
     <rparen> = <')'>"))


(simple2 "$(foo bar)")
; Parse error at line 1, column 11:
; $(foo bar)
;           ^
; Expected one of:
; ")"
; #"\s+"

(simple2 "$(foo () bar)")
; Parse error at line 1, column 14:
; $(foo () bar)
;              ^
; Expected one of:
; ")"
; #"\s+"
```

---

**Update 2** more test cases

```
(simple2 "$(foo bar ())")
(simple2 "$((foo bar baz))")
```

---

**Update 3** full working parser

For anyone curious, the full working parser, which was outside the scope of this question is:

```
(def parse
  "expr     - the top-level expression made up of cmds and sub-exprs. When multiple
              cmds are present, it implies they should be sucessively piped.
   cmd      - a single command consisting of words.
   sub-expr - a backticked or $(..)-style sub-expression to be evaluated inline.
   parened  - a grouping of words wrapped in parenthesis, explicitly tokenized to 
              allow parenthesis in cmds and disambiguate between sub-expression 
              syntax."
  (insta/parser
    "expr = cmd (<space> <pipe> <space> cmd)*
     cmd = words
     <sub-expr> = <backtick> expr <backtick> | nestable-sub-expr
     <nestable-sub-expr> = <dollar> <lparen> expr <rparen>
     words = word (<space>* word)*
     <word> = sub-expr | parened | word-chars
     <word-chars> = #'[^ `$()|]+'
     parened = lparen words rparen
     <space> = #'[ ]+'
     <pipe> = #'[|]'
     <dollar> = <'$'>
     <lparen> = '('
     <rparen> = ')'
     <backtick> = <'`'>"))
```

Example usage:

```
(parse "foo bar (qux) $(clj (map (partial * $(js 45 * 2)) (range 10))) `frob`")
```

Parses to:

```
[:expr [:cmd [:words "foo" "bar" [:parened "(" [:words "qux"] ")"] [:expr [:cmd [:words "clj" [:parened "(" [:words "map" [:parened "(" [:words "partial" "*" [:expr [:cmd [:words "js" "45" "*" "2"]]]] ")"] [:parened "(" [:words "range" "10"] ")"]] ")"]]]] [:expr [:cmd [:words "frob"]]]]]]
```

This is a parser for a chatbot I wrote, [yetibot](https://github.com/devth/yetibot). It replaces the previous mess of regex-based, by-hand parsing.

Comment: Do you really want a word to be able to include white-space, for example? And I don't see how your definition stops a word from *including* a $(); it seems like it only stops it from starting with $. If you're trying to parse a posix-shell-like language, then you're going to have explicitly parse quotes of various kinds. (If you're trying to parse a posix-shell-compatible language, then it's quite a bit trickier.)

Comment: It's a made-up posix-like lang–not compatible. No, it should not contain whitespace, that's a mistake.

Comment: @rici updated grammar above.

Comment: Had to update again - looks like something was cached and not parsing accurately.

Comment: It's still going to read the `)`. You could add `)` to the exclusions, but then it wouldn't be able to handle `()`. So I guess what you want is to allow words to have balanced parentheses provided there is no `$` before the `(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know instaparser, so I just read enough documentation to give me a false sense of security. I also didn't test, and I don't really know what your requirements are.

In particular, I don't know:

1) Whether $() can nest (your grammar makes that impossible, I think, but it seems odd to me)

2) Whether () can contain whitespace without being parsed as more than one word

3) Whether () can contain $()

You'll need to be clear on things like this in order to write the grammar (or, as it happens, to ask for advice).

**Update**: *Revised the grammar based on comments. I removed the productions for `$` `(` and `)` because they seemed unnecessary, and this way the angle-brackets feel easier to deal with.*

The following is based on answering the above questions "yes, no, yes" and some random assumptions about regex format. (I'm not totally clear on how angle-brackets work, but I don't think it will be easy to make parentheses output the way you want; I settled for just outputting them as single elements. If I figure out something, I'll edit it.)

```
<sequence> = element (<space> element)*
<element> = expr | paren_sequence | word
expr = <'$'> <'('> sequence <')'>
<word> = !('$'? '(') #'([^ $()]|\$[^(])+'
<paren_sequence> = '(' sequence ')' 
<space> = #'\\s+'
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks, this is really close. I'd like to preserve the parens when it's not a sub-expr (e.g. `$(...)`). So: `(simple3 "$(foo (a b c) bar)")` parses into `[:expr "foo" "a b c" "bar"]` but it should parse to `[:expr "foo" "(a b c)" "bar"]` or even `[:expr "foo" "(a" "b" "c)" "bar"]`.

Comment: To answer your questions: 1. Yes they should nest and my simplified grammar did not make that possible. 2. It's not important in this case - either way works. 3. Yes, it can. () should be treated like any other word characters, and normal words can contain sub-expressions.

Comment: @devth: feel free to give it a try (I didn't). :)

Comment: Hm. I might have to compromise and require that parens be escaped inside sub expressions. Not sure the grammar can support my requirements.

Comment: @devth: I'm still not clear what your requirements are. What makes parens complicated is that you want them to balance, so that if you have `word0 $(word1 (word2 word3) word4) word5`, the `expr` extends to `word4`. The easiest way to do that is to make the parens tokens. Another way is to define four word types: ordinary `words`; `(words`;  `words)`; and `(words)` (which are actually the same as ordinary `words`). Then you can rewrite the `paren_sequence` production  without actual parentheses. If that's what you want.

Comment: Accepting your answer since you got me closer to my final solution. I added the full parser to question above.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are two changes you have to make in order to get both of your examples to work.

**1) Add Negative Lookbehind**

First, you will need a negative **lookbehind** in the regex for `<word>`. That way it will drop all the occurrences of `)` as the last character:

```
 <word> = !(dollar lparen) #'[^ ]+(?<!\\))'
```

So this will fix your first test case:

```
(simple2 "$(foo bar)")
=> [:expr "foo" "bar"]
```

**2) Add grammar for the last word**

Now if you run your second test case it will fail:

```
(simple2 "$(foo () bar)")
=> Parse error at line 1, column 8:
   $(foo () bar)
          ^ 
   Expected one of: 
   ")" (followed by end-of-string)
   #"\s+"
```

This fails because we have told our grammar to drop the last `)` in all instances of `<word>`. We now have to tell our grammar how to differentiate between the last instance of `<word>` and other instances. We'll do this by adding a specific `<lastword>` grammar, and make all other instances of `<word>` optional. The full grammar would look like this:

```
(def simple2
  (insta/parser
    "expr = <dollar> <lparen> word* lastword <rparen>
     <word>  = !(dollar lparen) #'[^ ]+' <space>+
     <lastword> = !(dollar lparen) #'[^ ]+(?<!\\))' 
     <space> = #'\\s+'
     <dollar> = <'$'>
     <lparen> = <'('>
     <rparen> = <')'>"))
```

And your two test cases should work fine:

```
(simple2 "$(foo bar)")
=> [:expr "foo" "bar"]

(simple2 "$(foo () bar)")
=> [:expr "foo" "()" "bar"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks great. Working on building this into my larger grammar. I'm hitting `RuntimeException EOF while reading string` due to the `\\)` in `<lastword>`. Not sure why, since it's escaped. Did it work for you?

Comment: Just realized the EOF exception must have been a bug in `vim-fireplace`. It works if I paste directly in to `nrepl`!

Comment: Ok, cool. It was working for me. I was testing it in lein repl. Good luck!

Comment: A few other test cases I failed to mention are: `(simple2 "$(foo bar ())")` and `(simple2 "$((foo bar baz))")`. Struggling with how to support these.